# url in expressjs not giving the right query string

Tags: node.js, express

I am using expressjs in nodejs for creating my api. Now when I am sending a string as "Wed Jul 29 2015 17:34:22 GMT+0830" in the get request in the querystring and parsing it as url.parse(uri, true).query it gives me a string as "Wed Jul 29 2015 17:34:22 GMT 0830" without the '+'. How can I get the + in the string

Updating with the code

```
getEventTimeFromurl: function(ctx){

        var decodeURI = decodeURIComponent(ctx.req.url);
        var eventTime = undefined;
        const strEventTime = "eventTime=";

        var eventTimeindex = decodeURI.search(strEventTime);
        if (eventTimeindex == -1)
            throwError.badRequest(ctx, 101, 'Invalid event time');

        var aftereventtime = decodeURI.substring(eventTimeindex + strEventTime.length);
        var endIndex = aftereventtime.indexOf('&');
        if (endIndex == -1)
            eventTime = aftereventtime;
        else
            eventTime = aftereventtime.substring(0, endIndex);

        return eventTime;

    }
```

Here eventTime= is in the query string which have '+' sign like 'Mon Aug 03 2015 13:27:24 GMT+0930'.

Comment: So to be clear: the `getEventTimeFromurl` function is a solution to your problem, correct?

Comment: yes, this is what I tried and worked. a workaround

Answer (score 1):

You can encode string to URI format.

```
var dateString = "Wed Jul 29 2015 17:34:22 GMT+0830";
var encodedString = encodeURIComponent(dateString);
```

use encodedString to pass it in the query string.

Comment: Since the string is data which is passed by the client api, so I cannot encode or decode the date strings. Can I do something on the server side to get back the + that is being sent

Comment: No, you can not do anything on server side when you are sending plus keyword in querystring. server automatically consider it as a space.

Comment: You can use unix like timestamp variable to pass date if your client api provides it

Comment: No, its a format in string, and the apis are already released so it cannot be done on the client side. I need to parse it on the server side.

Comment: Try to use this. and try something to get it what you want :new Date( req.query.queryStringName)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of having `url.parse()` parse the query string, you can first replace any `+` characters in it by their URL-encoded version (`%2b`) and then parse the query string manually:

```
var qs = require('querystring');

var querystring = url.parse(uri).query.replace(/\+/g, '%2b');
var query       = qs.parse(querystring);
```

Although this assumes that *all* `+` characters in the query string need to be kept. If that's not acceptable, you can probably modify the regular expression to match only specific cases (like in timezone notations).

**EDIT**: combined with Express, it would look something like this:

```
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  var querystring = url.parse(req.url).query.replace(/\+/g, '%2b');
  var query       = qs.parse(querystring);
  ...
});
```

Comment: I took the url from the request, decoded it,  and searched for the parameter in the string.

Comment: @Nipun what do you mean?

Comment: var decodeURI = decodeURIComponent(ctx.req.url);
        var eventTime = undefined;
        const strEventTime = "eventTime=";        
        var eventTimeindex = decodeURI.search(strEventTime);
        if (eventTimeindex == -1)
            {
        
        var aftereventtime = decodeURI.substring(eventTimeindex + strEventTime.length);
        var endIndex = aftereventtime.indexOf('&');
        if (endIndex == -1)
            eventTime = aftereventtime;
        else
            eventTime = aftereventtime.substring(0, endIndex);

Comment: @Nipun please update your post with your code, comments aren't meant to post code in. Also explain a bit more, like what `ctx` is.

Comment: Here I am getting the decoded URI. Now from the URI I extract the time string from the query string and then use it.